# Converting blob --> byte array --> bitmap returns null bitmap in JAVA ANDROID

Tags: android, bitmap

I am storing Bitmap into my sql database by converting it to byte array and storing it as BLOB in sql table. And then later I am retrieving that BLOB from the table in a byte array and then converting it back to bitmap to display it in an image view.

For that I first converted bitmap to byte array like this:

```
Bitmap thumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(currentBitmap, 512, 384);
byte[] thumbBytes = getBytesFromBitmap(thumbnail, 10);
myDB.createNewDoc(tempName, currentTable, thumbBytes, dateCreated);
```

This is my getBytesFromBitmap() method:

```
public byte[] getBytesFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int quality) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, quality, out);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
```

Here currentBitmap is my original bitmap.

This is the sql query I am using to create my table that will contain a column in which bitmaps will be stored:

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DOCS_DATA (SNO INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, TABLE_NAME TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, THUMBNAIL BLOB, CREATEDON TEXT);");
```

Here second last column is THUMBNAIL of type BLOB which contains bitmaps converted into byte array.

And to insert data into this table I am using the following query:

```
public void createNewDoc(String doc_name, String table_name, byte[] thumbnail, String created_on) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO DOCS_DATA (NAME, TABLE_NAME, THUMBNAIL, CREATEDON) VALUES ('" + doc_name + "', '" + table_name + "', '" + thumbnail + "', '" + created_on + "');");
    }
```

Now to retrieve data from the table I am using the following method:

```
public ArrayList<Object> getAllDocs() {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> imagesNumber = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Bitmap> thumbnails = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> createdon = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cur = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT NAME, TABLE_NAME, THUMBNAIL, CREATEDON FROM DOCS_DATA ORDER BY SNO;", null);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < cur.getCount() ; i++) {
            cur.moveToPosition(i);
            names.add(cur.getString(0));
            byte[] img = cur.getBlob(2);
            Log.e("BLOB ---- ", ""+img.toString());
            Log.e("BLOB ---- ", ""+img.length);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
            Log.e("Bitmap", ""+bitmap);
            thumbnails.add(bitmap);
            createdon.add(cur.getString(3));
            Cursor cur1 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + cur.getString(1) + ";", null);
            imagesNumber.add(cur1.getCount());
            cur1.close();
        }
        cur.close();
        ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        objects.add(names);
        objects.add(imagesNumber);
        objects.add(thumbnails);
        objects.add(createdon);
        return objects;
    }
```

As you can see I have 3 Log.e(...) in this last part of code and this is what I am getting through these 3 logs:

```
E/BLOB ----: [B@ef5c8e2
E/BLOB ----: 29753
D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
E/Bitmap: null
```

And in the very first part of code that I posted here, where I am converting Bitmap to byte array. If I convert that byte array immediately to bitmap again, I am not getting null. And I am using same code to convert that byte array to bitmap that I am using in my getAllDocs method.

What could be the cause of this null Bitmap. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `am storing Bitmap into my sql database` No. You store a .webp image file in your database.

Comment: `of type BLOB which contains bitmaps converted into byte array.` No converted to .webp images.

Comment: `', '" + thumbnail + "', '" +` It is unclear what you try to store here. `thumbnail` was a bitmap according to your code. One cannot store bitmaps like that.

Comment: This thumbnail that you are pointing out here is of type byte[]. See first part of my code, I have updated it and included the line where I am calling createNewDoc() method. I am passing byte array with name thumbBytes

Comment: I see. But you cannot insert the content of a byte array in that way. And you said you would put it in a blob. And you did not react on most of my comments: you try to store .webp.  You better rewrite your post to tell what you really try to do.

Comment: How do I store bitmap into sql without converting it into byte array. And does it matter if its of type webp of jpeg or png, because ultimately its being converted to byte array

Comment: And if I am wrong here then what is the correct way of storing bitmap into sql table. I need to compress it like as well because it reduces image size a lot without affecting its quality.

Comment: Well you store bitmaps in sql by converting them to webp images. You store the webp image in sql. That the webp image is in a byte array at some time is pretty irrelevant is you try to explain what you do.

Comment: So you try to store .webp images in sql. Well ok. Go on. I never said that you should not do it. I only said that you did not really explain what you are doing.

Comment: Then how should I store the bitmap in sql table. What should be the correct steps according to you

Comment: My god.. you store .webp images. No bitmaps. And that is ok. Please reread and understand.

Comment: I got that. I read it later. Then why am I getting a null bitmap. And what is this error : D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Comment: Read! I already told you.

Comment: You are asking me to rewrite my post to tell what I am really trying to do. Is that what you mean. If yes then probably you need to do a bit of reading first instead of lecturing me. I already explained in first para. I want to store bitmap in sql table and later I want to retrieve it to display it in an image view.

Comment: Other than this I don't see anything useful that could answer why am I getting null bitmap

Comment: You are telling me I am not storing bitmap into sql instead I am storing .webp into it. Well then enlighten me. How do you directly store bitmap in a sql table.

Comment: And you can't claim that its .webp and not bitmap. .webp is just another compression format. Its getting converted into byte array before storing it into the table. Maybe you should not skip your homework